# Error: Invalid Python expression

Tags: python, animation, mesh, edit-mode, error

So I need help again. I am new to blender and am trying to follow a simple tutorial to add drivers to my model. So the guy in the video just put in the expressions and it worked. (And apparently there are no comments saying otherwise.) I mean, the video has a lot of thanks and praise comments. So either everyone is wrong, or there is something wrong with my blender. Here's a picture.

[image: This is an example. He put a lot of expression and for me, blender sent this error messenger]

Comment: In the box labeled "Expression", you're trying to use a variable named `var`, but you have named the variable `variavel` (with an accent mark I don't know how to reproduce) in the box labeled `(X)`, just below "Add Input Variable". The variable name(s) you use in "Expression" should match the variable names you define below "Add Input Variable".

Comment: @NeverConvex Thank you so much, bro. I'm Brazilian and I use Blender in Portuguese. Sometimes Blender's machine translation just translates something wrong or translates something it shouldn't even translate. Thanks for your help. <3

Comment: No problem! Glad it was helpful.